# Editing in UpgradeSchema.php method does not apply after running setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, upgradeschema

I have written a small module and I've made Setup classes include `InstallData, InstallSchema, UpgradeData, and UpgradeSchema` and put them in Setup folder, For the first time I did run `setup:upgrade` command everything was ok.

A table created and some data inserted. But then I tried to edit `UpgradeSchema.php` and `UpgradeData.php` to change table schema and data, but nothing happened.

I also changed `module.xml` and increase `setup_version to 0.0.3 or 0.0.4`, but it didn't work!

I commented the "`if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.2', '<'))`" condition, but nothing changed after `setup:upgrade` again!

Please help me what to do.

Comment: did you try to if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.3', '<'))?

Comment: In module.xml  I have setup_version=0.0.3, in UpdateSchema I have if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.3', '<')) and I commented all upgrade method in UpgradeData Class

Comment: in the UpgradeSchema change the if

Comment: Ok I changed it but UpdateSchema does not work

Comment: try changing to 0.0.5 everywhere and run setup:upgrade.

Comment: In setup_module table I have schema_version = 0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `module.xml` `setup_version` to `0.0.5` in `UpgradeSchema.php`

I changed the if clause

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.5', '<'))
```

And in `setup_module` table `schema_version in 0.0.1`.
should I change the table?